# Loading a preference on checkboxpreference click event

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to load a set of preferences(below) on a checkboxpreference/switchpreference on its corresponding click event.

My CheckBoxPreference is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="email_preference_checkbox"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_social_recommendations"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations">
</CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The preference i want to load is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <EditTextPreference
                android:capitalize="words"
                android:defaultValue="@string/default_I"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:key="d_I_key"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:title="@string/I_View" />

            <EditTextPreference
                android:capitalize="words"
                android:defaultValue="@string/de_name"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:key="d_i_key"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:title="@string/u_View" />

            <EditTextPreference
                android:capitalize="words"
                android:defaultValue="@string/de_d"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:key="e_d_key"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:title="@string/pa_iew" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Is there a way i can do it ? I was looking at the options for `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` but couldn't find a way to load the preferences. The preference i want to load on the click event, i had loaded it using a `PreferenceFragment`.

**EDIT**: I can see that there are 2 click event getting fired. One for enabling/disabling the check box and the other on clicking of the preference (similar to the `SwitchPreference` in android->Settings->WiFi). I want something similar to that.

Thanks.

Comment: What API you're using?

Comment: i want it for api's above honeycomb.